# How to get the entryCSN when using the LDAP_EXOP_MODIFY_PASSWD

Tags: c++, c, openldap

What I want is to use ldap_passwd function from OpenLdap to change the password and to make a request with the post read control that should response with the attribute I requested on the control.
The problem is I don't receive any data from the request control just the password is change.
The same comportment is when I use the ldappasswd functionality.
Here is my command:

```
$ ldappasswd -H ldap://localhost:389 -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w secret -epostread=entryCSN -a secret -s secret -ZZ
```

The question is why I don't receive any data from the server?

Comment: Ok sorry for that.